# Generate WP-CLI @alias for each site on multisite

Tags: multisite, configuration, wp-cli, automation, command-line

I have a few multisites, each with several sites, that I want to auto-generate [@aliases](https://wp-cli.org/commands/cli/alias/) for. Is there way to sync those sites as aliases in my [site list](https://wp-cli.org/commands/site/list/)?

I'd like to be able to target a single site without having to specify `--url=http://domain.com/sub-site/` and using the last part of the url seems like a viable name for the [alias](https://wp-cli.org/blog/version-0.24.0.html#effortlessly-use-wp-cli-against-any-wordpress-install).

```
$ wp site list
+---------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| blog_id | url                                    | last_updated        | registered          |
+---------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1       | http://domain.com/sub-site/            | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2020-01-00 04:20:00 | 
+---------+----------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+


$ wp cli alias
---
@all: Run command against every registered alias.
@sub-site:
  url: http://domain.com/sub-site/
  path: /www/wordpress


$ wp @sub-site theme list
---
...
```

I can only find the following commands that may help;

Shows current aliases:

> $ wp cli alias

Shows all sites

> $ wp site list --field=url

---

(Ideal) Auto generate aliases:

> $ wp site aliases
>
> $ wp cli alias --generate

---

Whatever the solution, it should include the `path:` to WordPress for that site and (optional) be able to produce unique aliases that have not already been added to `~/.wp-cli/config.yml`.

---

**WIP**

`home=$(wp eval "echo get_home_path();"); url=$(wp eval "echo site_url();"); for site in $(wp site list --field=url | sort); do alias_name=$(sed "s,/,,g" <<< $(sed "s,$url,,g" <<< "$site")); if [ ! -z "$alias_name" ]; then echo -e "@$alias_name:\n     url: $site\n    path: $home\n"; fi; done;`

or 
`path=$(wp eval "echo get_home_path();"); url=$(wp eval "echo site_url();"); wp site list --field=url | sort | cut -d '/' -f4 | xargs -I '{}' echo -e "@{}:\n url: $url/{}\n path: $path\n"`

`| sort | sed -r "s#($url)##g" | cut -d '/' -f2 | xargs`

`| sort | tail -n+2 | cut -d '/' -f 4 | xargs`

`| sort | cut -d '/' -f4 | xargs`

```
@site-a:
 url: http://domain.com/site-a/
 path: /www/wordpress/

@site-b:
 url: http://domain.com/site-b/
 path: /www/wordpress/
```

Next step would be to, validate the alias against existing aliases. And include sorting by site path

*Sort:*
`sites=$(wp site list --field=url); readarray -t sorted < <(for a in "${sites[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done | sort); for a in "${sorted[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done`

*Sort:*
`wp site list --field=url | sort`

*Existing alias:*
`wp cli alias | grep '^@' | grep ':$' | cut -d':' -f3`

**Remote Alias Generator (run on server)**

`ssh=user@127.0.0.1;cd /www/wordpress/;home=$(wp eval "echo get_home_path();"); url=$(wp eval "echo site_url();"); for site in $(wp site list --field=url); do alias_name=$(sed "s,/,,g" <<< $(sed "s,$url,,g" <<< "$site")); if [ ! -z "$alias_name" ]; then echo -e "@prefix-$alias_name:\n     url: $site\n    ssh: $ssh$home\n"; fi; done;`

Comment: I'm thinking xargs could be part of the toolset to do this ...

Comment: It's a bit tedious for someone coming `drush`. One approach is [to add](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/5246) `require:
  - my-wp-cli.php` to `config.yml`, and figure out how to generate the aliases in `~/.wp-cli/my-wp-cli.php`. I went down that path but backtracked and ended up generating my `config.yml` with ansible (for now).

Answer (score 1):

---

**LOCAL**

---

For local aliases, it works best to define your path ahead of time in the config.yml. Then keep the variables pretty clean by only specifying the `url` to target the site. Sorting the output helps if you have a long list of sites since the default is by blog id (which we're not using).

`wp site list --field=url|sort|xargs -I 'SITE' sh -c 'ALIAS=$(cut -d'/' -f4 <<< SITE);if [ ! -z "$ALIAS" ];then echo -e "@$ALIAS:\n  url: SITE";fi'`

**Result**

```
path: /www/wordpress/

@site-a:
  url: http://domain.com/site-a/
@site-b:
  url: http://domain.com/site-b/
```

---

**REMOTE**

---

For remote aliases, it's nicer to prefix them relative to the config.yml. So in this case, `remote-`. Also you can tack the WordPress path onto the `ssh` property.

`HOME=$(wp eval "echo get_home_path();");wp site list --field=url|sort|xargs -I 'SITE' sh -c 'ALIAS=$(cut -d'/' -f4 <<< SITE);if [ ! -z "$ALIAS" ];then echo -e "@remote-$ALIAS:\n  url: SITE\n  ssh=user@127.0.0.1$HOME";fi'`

**Result:**

```
@remote-site-a:
  url: http://domain.com/site-a/
  ssh: user@127.0.0.1/www/wordpress/
@remote-site-b:
  url: http://domain.com/site-b/
  ssh: user@127.0.0.1/www/wordpress/
```

---

**LIST ALIASES**

---

```
aliases=$(wp cli alias | cut -d':' -f1 | grep -e "^@" | cut -d':' -f2 | sort);
```

---

**EXISTING ALIASES**

---

```
aliases=$(wp cli alias | cut -d':' -f1 | grep -e "^@" | cut -d':' -f2 | sort);

search="@site-a"

if ! grep $search <<< "$aliases"; then echo "NOT FOUND"; fi
```

---

**BASH REFERENCE**

---

- `VAR=$(echo "stuff")` - Capture output
- `HOME=$(wp eval "echo get_home_path();")` - Run PHP and assign to var
- `wp site list --field=url | sort` - Sorts the resulting site list
- `| xargs -I 'SITE'` - For loop from pipe and use SITE as the value variable
- `| xargs -I %` - Pick a symbol that makes sense
- `xargs -I 'ITEM' sh -c 'echo ITEM; echo "2nd";'` - Run multiple bash commands
- `cut -d'/' -f4 <<< SITE` - Split from variable
- `ALIAS=$(cut -d'/' -f4 <<< SITE)` - Split URL on '/', assign the 4th index to var
- `echo -e "\txyz\n\n"` - Allow escaped characters
- `if [ ! -z "$ALIAS" ];then echo -e "";fi` - Run on non-empty variable
- `wp cli alias | grep '^@' | grep ':$'` - Multiple filters on results array
- `grep '^starts-with'` - Line starts with value
- `grep 'ends-with$'` - Line ends with value
- `sed "s,$url,,g" <<< "$site"` - sed string replace with `,` separator
- `sed "s/find/replace/g" <<< "$value"` - sed string replace with `/` separator (not good with urls)
- `wp site list --field=url | tail -n+2` - Skip first item
- `alias_name=$(sed "s,/,,g" <<< $(sed "s,$url,,g" <<< "$site"))` - Multiple string replacements
- `for i in $(wp site list --field=url); do echo $i; done;` - Loop through list